# Generate an XML doc from the DOM while skipping over certain elements

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, dom-traversal

I have HTML that I'm trying to generate an XML document from. I want to skip certain elements (basically all but my divs) and for this purpose, I've written a simple DOM traversal function, but I seem to be getting stuck in an infinite loop. (More details below.)

### So I have HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div id="browserDiv">
    <h3>Library</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div id="t-0" class="section topic" data-content="2b-2t-38-w-2c-2w-2t-33-36-3d">
                <p>Set Theory</p>
                <img class="toggle"><img class="edit">
                <img class="add-entry"><img class="delete">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div id="t-0-0" class="section topic" data-content="1t-3c-2x-33-31-37">
                            <p>Axioms</p>
                            <img class="toggle"><img class="edit">
                            <img class="add-entry"><img class="delete">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div id="t-0-0-0" class="section topic" data-content="1t-3c-2x-33-31-w-33-2u-w-2b-2t-34-2p-36-2p-38-2x-33-32">
                                        <p>Axiom of Separation</p>
                                        <img class="toggle"><img class="edit">
                                        <img class="add-entry"><img class="delete">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <img class="add-new">
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <img class="add-new">
                                </li>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="add-new">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="t-1" class="section topic" data-content="1t-32-2p-30-3d-37-2x-37">
                <p>Analysis</p>
                <img class="toggle"><img class="edit">
                <img class="add-entry"><img class="delete">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img class="add-new">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="add-new">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And I'm trying to convert this html into an XML file. But the XML only stores info contained in the `div` elements, so I'm trying to skip over all the other elements when I iterate through the DOM tree.

### The sort of XML I'm aiming to produce (eventually):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library userid="095209376">
    <title>UserID095209376's Library</title>
    <topic children="yes" loadable="no">
        <id>0</id>
        <encoding>2b-2t-38-w-2c-2w-2t-33-36-3d</encoding>
        <topic children="yes" loadable="no">
            <id>0-0</id>
            <encoding>1t-3c-2x-33-31-37</encoding>
            <topic children="no" loadable="yes">
                <id>0-0-0</id>
                <encoding>1t-3c-2x-33-31-w-33-2u-w-2b-2t-34-2p-36-2p-38-2x-33-32</encoding>
            </topic>
        </topic>
    <topic children="yes" loadable="no">
        <id>1</id>
        <encoding>1t-32-2p-30-3d-37-2x-37</encoding>
    </topic>
</library>
```

### Here's how I'm iterating through it currently:

(Note that the script tags are only there to get SO to do syntax highlighting.)

```
<script>
function saveLibrary(){

    var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.tuningcode.com', 'library');
    var rootNode = document.getElementById('browserDiv');
    console.log("rootNode here: " + rootNode);
    var libraryTree = walkLibraryTree2(rootNode, xmlDoc);
    xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(libraryTree);
    var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
    console.log("xmlDoc: " + xmlDoc);
    console.log(sXML);

}

function walkLibraryTree2(nodeToWalk, doc){

    var elem = doc.createElement(nodeToWalk.tagName);
    console.log(elem);
    if(nodeToWalk.hasChildNodes()){
        var ch = nodeToWalk.children;
        for(var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
            var theWalk = walkLibraryTree2(ch[i], doc);
            if(theWalk != null){
                if(ch[i].tagName == 'DIV'){
                    elem.appendChild(theWalk);
                } else{
                    elem = theWalk;
                }
            }
        }
        return elem;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

saveLibrary();
</script>
```

The problem is that when I run it, (edit) it takes much longer than it should and produces something like this:

```
<library xmlns="http://www.tuningcode.com"><LI xmlns=""/></library>.
```

In other words, it doesn't print any of the divs, and only one li element. I have it printing to the console quite a bit, and even with only with the amount of nodes shown above, it's printing thousands of statements to the console.

### The question:

How can I traverse the tree skipping all but the `div` elements? Or why is the code above not working correctly?

### Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bGjH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're encountering that very long running time because you call `walkLibraryTree2` twice for every iteration of your `for` loop, resulting in an exponential expansion (your HTML is 13 levels deep, so that means `walkLibraryTree2` is called over 8,000 times).

When working with a complicated problem, it's a good idea to break it down into smaller parts. The following seems to work:

```
<script>
function saveLibrary() {
    var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, 'library');
    var rootNode = document.getElementById('browserDiv');
    console.log("rootNode here: " + rootNode);

    appendNodes(xmlDoc.documentElement, processChildren(rootNode, xmlDoc));

    var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var sXML = oSerializer.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
    console.log("xmlDoc: " + xmlDoc);
    console.log(sXML);
}

// DomNode, Document -> Array[DomNode]
function processChildren(node, doc) {
    var nodes = [],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes = nodes.concat(processNode(node.childNodes[i], doc));
    }

    return nodes;
}

// DomNode, Array[DomNode] -> void
function appendNodes(destNode, nodes) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        destNode.appendChild(nodes[i]);
    }
}

// DomNode, Document -> Array[DomNode]
function processNode(node, doc) {
    var children = processChildren(node, doc);

    if (node.tagName == "DIV") {
        return [createTopicElement(node, doc, children)];
    } else {
        return children;
    }
}

// DomNode, Document, Array[DomNode] -> DomNode
function createTopicElement(baseNode, doc, children) {
    var el = doc.createElement("topic"),
        hasChildren = !! children.length,
        id = node.id.substring(2),
        encoding = node.getAttribute("data-content");

    el.setAttribute("children", hasChildren ? "yes" : "no");
    el.appendChild(createElementWithValue(doc, "id", id));
    el.appendChild(createElementWithValue(doc, "encoding", encoding));
    appendNodes(el, children);

    return el;
}

// Document, String, String -> DomNode
function createElementWithValue(doc, name, value) {
    var el = doc.createElement(name);
    el.textContent = value;
    return el;
}

saveLibrary();    
</script>
```

This produces the XML:

```
<library>
    <topic children="yes">
        <id>0</id>
        <encoding>2b-2t-38-w-2c-2w-2t-33-36-3d</encoding>
        <topic children="yes">
            <id>0-0</id>
            <encoding>1t-3c-2x-33-31-37</encoding>
            <topic children="no">
                <id>0-0-0</id>
                <encoding>1t-3c-2x-33-31-w-33-2u-w-2b-2t-34-2p-36-2p-38-2x-33-32</encoding>
            </topic>
        </topic>
    </topic>
    <topic children="no">
        <id>1</id>
        <encoding>1t-32-2p-30-3d-37-2x-37</encoding>
    </topic>
</library>
```

I don't know how your `loadable` attribute is determined, or where the title comes from, but this should get you most of the way there.

http://jsfiddle.net/Weu4A/4/

Comment: Thank you so much! You went way over and above what I was asking. I'll take some time to look over the code you've written before I can really respond to it. I'm missing where you say I'm calling it twice though. To me it looks like I call it once?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Ah, you're right. You were calling it twice in your previous version of the question that you deleted.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I re-implemented the algorithm more in line with my original (albeit spaghetti-ish) code using yours to help me understand where mine was going wrong. Works now! :) JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5KgN/20/ Thanks again!